# 3d Camera Tilting when Camera Tracked

Tags: tracking

I tried to 3d camera track my footage in blender and my solve error was 1.1846 and I didn't think that was that bad. I set the lens to 14mm because that was the lens I was using with my Panasonic g7, I did the refine K1, K2 thing and I set three points as the floor and set one as the origin so I don't know what went wrong. I was using a Steadicam as well so I think it was pretty stable

What it looked like:

https://f.io/E6uErcMW

https://f.io/2dMnFjAf

I just started blender not long ago so it is probably something obvious lol

Comment: You need more accurate tracking. Your trackers are bunched up in a very small portion of the frame, add trackers closer to the edge of the frame. Place the trackers in different planes Track elements that are closer to the camera and others that are further away (in the plants in the background). A solve error over 1 is still too high, try to get your solve error down to  0.3 or less. Read this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped, I will tell you if it works :)

Comment: I spread out the trackers and got the solve down to 2, it did this: f.io/C4DNRxwr

Comment: I tried to delete the trackers over a solve error of 2 but then I got a solve error of 150. I am really confused

Comment: It was also giving me an error that said "some data failed to reconstruct"

Comment: read the link again. accurate tracking of well distributed features is the key.